# Kendo Upload upgrade(MVC) - OnUploadSelect code change

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-upload

With the older version of telerik, we had a snippet of code to find the number of childnodes as given below

```
function onUploadSelect(ev) {
var numberOfFiles;
if (ev.target.childNodes[1] != undefined && ev.target.childNodes[1] != null) {
    numberOfFiles = ev.target.childNodes[1].childNodes.length;
}
if ((numberOfFiles + ev.files.length) > 4) { 
//some custom validation error msgs being thrown
}
}
```

the basic logic of this code is to prevent uploading more than 4 files, 
Ex - i select 2 files,dont click on upload instead select a file again and then click on upload, I'm good(2+1<4) 
With the KEndo Uplaod, ev.target is undefined,
can you suggest a possible alternative for this?

Thanks
Adarsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**Kendo-HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<title>Test</title>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="demo-section">
                    <input name="files" id="files" type="file" />
</div>
<script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#files").kendoUpload({
                       select: onSelect
                    });
                });

        function onSelect(e) {
                    if (e.files.length > 4) {
               alert("Please select max 4 files.");
               e.preventDefault();
            }
                else {
               var existingfileCount = $(".demo-section li").length;
               if((e.files.length + existingfileCount) > 4)  
               {
                   alert("You can not upload more than 4 files");
                   e.preventDefault();
                   }

                }
                }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Kendo-MVC**

> Javascript

```
<script>
             function onSelect(e) {
                    if (e.files.length > 4) {
               alert("Please select max 4 files.");
               e.preventDefault();
            }
                else {
               var existingfileCount = $(".demo-section li").length;
               if((e.files.length + existingfileCount) > 4)  
               {
                   alert("You can not upload more than 4 files");
                   e.preventDefault();
                   }

                }
                }
</script>
```

> View.cshtml

```
<div class="demo-section">
        @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
            .Name("files")
            .Events(events => events.Select("onSelect"))
        )
</div>
```

Note : I have used 'demo-section' class to simplyfy the code. If you want to rename this class then rename this class in html/cshtml and javascript.

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: I did not understand the code snippet in document. ready, I mean how is the count incremented? $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#files").kendoUpload({
                       select: onSelect
                    });
                });

Comment: I have updated my above code snippet. I have tried to achieve your functionality without using hiddenfield because if we do not manage its value properly then it will create problems. Like on file deletion/selecting we have to change the hiddenfield value. One more thing it will also create performance issue in page.

Comment: when ever file count is needed i will get from UI or from upload control. So, it will work after adding new files and after deleting existing files.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is what you want ,

```
function onSelect(e) {
  var ct = $('#Count').val();
  if (e.files.length > 4) {
   alert("Please select max 4 files.");
   e.preventDefault();
  }
  else {
   ct= parseInt(ct == "" ? 0 : ct);
   $('#Count').val(ct + e.files.length);
  }
}

@Html.Hidden("Count")
```

to restrict user to not upload  more then 4 file. If i understand right.

Comment: When i select 4 files at one shot, the e.files.length will be 4, where as if i select 1, then without clicking upload, select one more, for the second file e.files.length will be 1(and not the summation 2). I am trying to get that sum value. So before clicking upload the total number of files browsed and selected should be less than or equal to 4.

Comment: @AdarshK i just update my code. if you have any concern then let me know.